# Sufficient criterion for a function in C to be differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Give a sufficient criterion for a function f(z), z $\epsilon$ C to be differentiable at $z=z_0$.

I know that continuity does not imply differentiability, can't think of a criterion that implies differentiability, help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ has to be a differentiable function as a function from $\mathbb R^2\mapsto\mathbb R^2$, and then also satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann condition.

You can find it in Robert Ash's Complex Variables [online](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/CV.html).